# Identifying a software issue that drains battery (after new battery install)

Tags: battery, restore, power

I've got an iPhone 12 with the latest iOS updates. After the battery was draining quite quickly at 81% health, I took the phone to an Apple certified repair shop and had a new battery installed.

The health indicator shows 100% but the battery still drains quite quickly. (I'm usually at 60% by midday after very light use.)

I performed a factory reset and restored from my iCloud backup but noticed no difference.

In the Battery settings section, it shows that Instagram is using 20-40% of power most of the time, but even after un/reinstalling and closing Instagram manually after use, there is no difference.

**Is it possible to figure out what app/software issue is causing the battery to drain?  Any other ideas of how I can stop the battery drain?**

Comment: Was battery life better without Instagram being installed?

Comment: Unfortunately, not really. 